# "Close" event of Modal in Beufy

Tags: vue.js, vuex

How to trigger close event in Beufy? I tried the code below but I cannot see my console. I am suppose to do something before "closing".

```
this.$modal.open({
                parent: this,
                component: myComponent,
                hasModalCard: true,
                canCancel: true,
                events: {
                    close: (value) => {
                        console.log('im here!', value)
                    }
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

So I figure out how to trigger an event before closing my modal on submit.

First, I created a custom event inside my modal in the "Parent" component:

```
this.$modal.open({
                parent: this,
                component: myComponent,
                hasModalCard: true,
                canCancel: true,
                events: {
                    afterSubmit: (value) => {
                        // Do something here. In my case, I am setting something in a field in my parent from Store.
                    }
                }
            })
```

Second, I did an $emit inside my "Child" component in the function where I am calling on "Submit" button.

```
submitForm() {
   this.$emit('afterSubmit', value)
}
```